# Weird contraints difference of two basically identical UILabels in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I created a UITableView with static sections. My problem is, that within those sections, the constraints behave "weird".

[image]

The constraints problems are in all sections, but I focus on Label3 and Label4.

[image]

As you can see, the labels are siblings that have different leading and trailing constraint values to superview, although they position identically in the horizontal plane.

You can check the storyboard, that both labels are configured identically, except for font and position. I could post screenshots of those Xcode tabs as well, but I think it's easier just to look at the storyboard, which is in this Xcode project: [StaticTableView.zip](https://www.sendspace.com/file/my12q3).

I have run out of ideas, what the source of the problem could be. But I don't want those non-sensical values in my constraints.

### Addendum: Root of trouble

As explained in the answer, this is the reason for the differing constraint values.

[image: Contraints with marging and without]

Comment: Are you getting any related warnings from Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the trailing constraint properties to have `Label4` same as `Label3`. Just select and double click on your current trailing constraint of both and check the difference. You have to set the `Label4's` constraint as given below in the pic. Then you can see both values are same.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes by default while placing the label it takes those, and setting some constraints or wrong constraints xib automatically apply some constraints to satisfy the element placement,  due to that it happens.

Comment: I can see now that my problem was, that I only looked in the constraints inspector of the view (as seen in my screenshot). This did not show that one of the label contraints were relative to margin. When I looked at the single contraints with the inspector (like your screenshot) it became clear.

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot to clarify my last comment. Thank to @viivekDas for the invaluable help.